# override and implement fn from class in interface

Tags: kotlin, overriding, traits

I want to override toString() in an interface and have objects that implement that interface to default to using that method (eg: not shadowed)

```
interface SingletonObjectTrait {
  fun toString(): String = this.javaClass.simpleName
}
```

Is there a straightforward way to define such an interface, preferably with minimal configuration at implementation

```
object MyEvent: SomeEventLogic(), SomeEventType, SingletonObjectTrait
class SomeEventLogic {}
interface SomeEventType {}
```

Comment: That's not possible. Your only option is to make it an abstract class, but then you'll loose you extends from your other class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't a great way to do this other than using maybe an annotation processor to add the missing override at compile time (*by adding an annotation to the interface that you detect and you generate the overrides in the implementation class*).  **This would work**, but may be biting off more than you want to, and is likely out of scope of an answer here on Stack Overflow (seek "*how to write an annotation processor for Java or Kotlin*" and "*KAPT*" for the one engine that supports Kotlin processors).

Back to your code and why it will not work as-is:

An interface cannot have a method with a signature that matches any of the methods in `Any` class.  And if you try to override one of them you will get a compilation error.

> An interface may not implement a method of 'Any'

The minimal code to do something like you want is:

```
interface SingletonObjectTrait {
    fun asString(): String = this.javaClass.simpleName
}

open class SomeEventLogic {}
interface SomeEventType {}

object MyEvent: SomeEventLogic(), SomeEventType, SingletonObjectTrait {
    override fun toString(): String = asString() // hope they don't forget to call this!
}
```

There is no guarantee the implementer will call the trait `asString()` function but at least you can share the functionality with a one-liner in the implementing class.

Answer (score 8):

That's not possible, I'm afraid.

Method implementations in interfaces work much like default methods in Java: they're used only if the implementing class doesn't have an implementation already.  But *every* class already inherits `toString()` from `Any`, so the default would never be used.

In fact, the compiler has a specific error for this — if you try to implement `toString()` in an interface, it says:

> An interface may not implement a method of 'Any'

I can't see a good way around this.

As Erik says, one option is to change the interface to an abstract class; but of course that's not viable if any implementations already extend another class.

Another option might be to implement a *different* method in the interface, and in the comments instruct implementing classes to override `toString()` and call that method.  Not automatic, but less work for implementers, and less repetition.